# Profiling firebase storage requests

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have an app which uses firebase storage and I am observing an unusual traffic to the storage. The bandwidth usage is unusually high, which shouldn't happen with the usual behavior of the app.

I need to isolate a user or a stored file which causes this unusual bandwidth usage. Is there any way I can get more information about the storage usage, other than the information shown at the Usage tab of firebase console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Storage only tracks and shows aggregate data for the usage in your project. It does not tie this usage to specific Firebase Authentication users.

If you need that, consider adding your own tracking for this, for example by logging uploads/downloads to Google Analytics for Firebase.

You can also log to Stack Driver, although it might only be in aggregate there too. For the exact metrics, see the [Google Cloud Platform documentation on its storage metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-storage).

Alternatively you could [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. But I'm not sure if they have access to the type of data you're looking for.